# how to use jsonb in sqlalchemy expression language to compare with integer in select expression?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How to access jsonb dictionary value using sqlalchemy core expression language? eg:

```
 s1 = select([issues.c.id,
             issues.c.data['product_id'],
             products.c.name.label('product_name')
             ]). \
    where(issues.c.id == issue_id). \
    select_from(issues.
    outerjoin(products,
    (issues.c.data['product_id']).cast(Integer) == (products.c.id)))
```

Data stored in the issues table is as follows:

```
id    | data------+
5247  | {"priority": "M", "product_id": "1"}
```

How exactly do I use this expression for joining the table. The above gives error as:`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: jsonb = integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it by adding astext before converting to integer:

```
s1 = select([issues.c.id,
             issues.c.data['product_id'],
             products.c.name.label('product_name')
             ]). \
    where(issues.c.id == issue_id). \
    select_from(issues.
    outerjoin(products,
    (issues.c.data['product_id']).astext.cast(Integer) == (products.c.id)))
```